# Concurrent Operation subclass combining KVO compliance and thread safety

Tags: swift

This is a subclass of `Operation` that attempts to combine the requirements of KVO compliance and thread safety. Do I have the KVO notifications and thread safety done correctly?

```
class ConcurrentOperation: Operation {
    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "operation", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var _isExecuting = false
    private var _isFinished = false

    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            return stateQueue.sync { _isExecuting }
        }
        set {
            stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isExecuting = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            return stateQueue.sync { _isFinished }
        }
        set {
            stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isFinished = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            finish()
            return
        }
        print("starting...")
        willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        isExecuting = true
        didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        main()
    }
    
    override func main() {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            if self.isCancelled {
                print("cancelled")
            } else {
                print("done")
            }
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    func finish() {
        if isExecuting {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            isExecuting = false
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
        
        if !isFinished {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            isFinished = true
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }
}

let op1 = ConcurrentOperation()
let op2 = ConcurrentOperation()

let opQueue = OperationQueue()
opQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
opQueue.addOperation(op1)
opQueue.addOperation(op2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks fine re KVO and thread-safety.

---

A few stylistic observations:

1. I would personally move the `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` into the setters. It feels a little cluttered to have them sprinkled about the implementation. This pattern in your code snippet harkens [back to the original Objective-C implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW16), but Swift provides us opportunities to tidy up this code.
2. I know you got your keynames right, but I always use `#keyPath(isExecuting)` and `#keyPath(isFinished)` to have the compiler enforce the string values.
3. I would make both `isExecuting` and `isFinished` read-only properties (with `private(set)`) as no external code has any business changing these values.
4. Personally, I would pull the `main` implementation out of `ConcurrentOperation` and put it into its own subclass. Once you have this `ConcurrentOperation` defined, you will find yourself using it everywhere you do not want to repeat all this boilerplate code in every concurrent operation subclass.

Thus:

```swift
class ConcurrentOperation: Operation {
    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "operation", attributes: .concurrent)

    private var _isExecuting = false
    private var _isFinished = false

    override private(set) var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            stateQueue.sync { _isExecuting }
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
            stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isExecuting = newValue
            }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
        }
    }

    override private(set) var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            stateQueue.sync { _isFinished }
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
            stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isFinished = newValue
            }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
        }
    }

    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            finish()
            return
        }
        isExecuting = true
        main()
    }

    override func main() {
        fatalError("This must be overridden")
    }

    func finish() {
        if isExecuting {
            isExecuting = false
        }

        if !isFinished {
            isFinished = true
        }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
class TwoSecondOperation: ConcurrentOperation {
    override func main() {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            if self.isCancelled {
                print("cancelled")
            } else {
                print("done")
            }
            self.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Going a step further, we generally strive for cancelable `Operation` subclasses, where possible. E.g., in this example, rather than using a closure with `asyncAfter`, we should instead used a `DispatchWorkItem`. Then we could make this operation truly cancelable (rather than having to wait two seconds before the cancelation is recognized).

For example, perhaps something like the following:

```swift
class TwoSecondOperationImproved: ConcurrentOperation {
    private var item: DispatchWorkItem?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        item = DispatchWorkItem {
            if self.isCancelled {
                print("cancelled")
            } else {
                print("done")
            }
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    override func main() {
        if let item = item {
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: item)
        }
    }

    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        item?.cancel()
        finish()
    }

    override func finish() {
        item = nil
        super.finish()
    }
}
```

In short, if the asynchronous task being wrapped in `ConcurrentOperation` offers cancelation, make sure to override `cancel`, too.

---

If you prefer, you can also use locks to synchronize the properties of `ConcurrentOperation`:

```swift
class ConcurrentOperation: Operation {
    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var _isExecuting = false
    private var _isFinished = false

    override private(set) var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            synchronized { _isExecuting }
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
            synchronized { _isExecuting = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
        }
    }

    override private(set) var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            synchronized { _isFinished }
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
            synchronized { _isFinished = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
        }
    }

    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            finish()
            return
        }
        isExecuting = true
        main()
    }

    override func main() {
        fatalError("This must be overridden")
    }

    func finish() {
        if isExecuting {
            isExecuting = false
        }

        if !isFinished {
            isFinished = true
        }
    }

    private func synchronized<T>(block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        try lock.synchronized { try block() }
    }
}

extension NSLocking {
    func synchronized<T>(block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return try block()
    }
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's safe to call `didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))` in the setter right after `stateQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {}`. If it's asynchronous, how can we be certain the KVO will be notified before the new value is applied in the closure? Wouldn't it be safer to move the KVO notifications inside the closure? And as a side note, would it really be so bad to dispatch the setter's queue synchronously?

Comment: It’s safe to call `didChangeValue` outside the closure because the observer will use the getter to determine what the value actually is, and that will wait for the barrier anyway. For this reason, it’s actually important to call `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` _outside_ of the synchronization because you can otherwise deadlock/crash. That having been said, I actually use locks in my code (i.e., everything synchronous) because although reader-writer feels like it should be more efficient, in practice it isn’t; it’s slower. And simple lock synchronization is easier to reason about, IMHO.

Comment: When you say you use locks in your code, do you just mean that all of your thread-safe properties have synchronous dispatching in their setters? Can you append your answer to include an example of what this would look like?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already added that to the end of the answer…

Comment: Thank you! I think my final question is how is this locking mechanism different from, or better than, simply removing the barrier flag from the setter's queue and just using a serial queue with sync dispatching for all reads and writes?

Comment: Because locks achieve the intuitive synchronous behavior you are looking for and are even faster than reader-writer. But if you just want to use a serial queue with `sync`, that works, too, though slower than reader-writer with no real benefit. But the differences are likely to be immaterial, so use whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I've read a lot of your posts on SO and you are definitely a guru in concurrency and your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Rob: Isn't this a question for you https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272943/35991 ? :)